Use determinant to compute the volume of a "box" with vertices $(0,0,0), (3,1,1), (1,3,1), (1,1,3)$
So I graphed the vectors and it formed a pyramid instead of a "box":

I know that the volume of a "box" or parallelepiped is the triple product or the determinant of a $3 \times 3$ matrix.
I've computed it and got $20$ cubic units. However, I have a feeling that this is a trick question and I can't trust myself.
An alternative approach that comes to mind is to compute the area of the "base" of the pyramid spanned by these three vectors, find the height by finding the "minimal distance" between the origin and the base, and plug it into the pyramid formula.
However, that seems like too much work, and I was wondering if there's any easier solution


You can compare to  other similar computations, e.g., here. Do the same for your given vertices.

@DietrichBurde I was specifically asked to find it using determinants though

Yes, the last answer does this, with the "box" product and determinant. But you don't want it, you said, because it is a "trick question". So ...you can compute the planes instead. You mentioned "An alternative approach", so why not.

This is analogous to asking for the volume of a box that has vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(1, 0,0)$, $(0, 1, 0)$ and $(0, 0, 1)$. That "box" also has 4 OTHER vertices $(1,1,0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1)$, and $(1,1,1)$. Yours is similar. The problem is telling you SOME of the vertices, and asking you to find the whole volume. (I think it's a crappy question, because there might be multiple parallelipeds that have those four vertices, but that's beside the point.)
[It'd be better if it said "and also has edges with directions this,
this, and that, at which point it'd be unambiguous.]
Post-comment addition
It turns out that knowing four vertices of a parallelepiped in 3-space is not enough to know its volume. [Knowing 3 vertices of a parallelogram in 2-space is enough!]
As an example, the unit cube has the vertices
0 0 0
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
1 1 0
1 0 1
0 1 1
1 1 1

and its volume is, of course, $1$. But if we take a particular four of its vertices and extend to a parallelepiped, namely
0 0 0 
1 1 0
1 0 1
0 1 1
2 1 1
1 1 2
1 2 1
2 2 2

then you end up with a volume of 2 instead!
If you are given three edges of a parallelepiped, that suffices...but then again, from any three edges, you can generate the remaining vertices and edges, so the parallelepiped is uniquely determined.
Post-post-comment addition:
Using the prior example as a model, here's a parallelepiped containing your vertices, but having a different volume:
let s = 3/2 and t = -1/2 and r = 5/2
0 0 0
t s s   (call this "u")
s t s   (call this "v")
s s t   (call this "w")
1 1 3   (which is u + v)
3 1 1   (which is v + w)
1 1 3   (which is u + w)
r r r   (which is u + v + w)

The formulas on the right-hand side show that this is a parallelepiped. Brute force computation of a determinant shows that this has a volume of 10, while the "more obvious" parallelepiped has a volume of 20.
So it really is a crappy problem.

I understand that the box is not unambiguously defined but just wanted to make sure: the volume of any of those boxes is the same, right?

Ooh. Good question. In 2D the answer is certainly "yes", applying cavallieri's principle. In 3D I think it's also "yes", but I need to play a bit more. In 4D (with 5 vertices) it's just possible that the answer is "no", playing off the linear growth in the number of vectors needed to specify a parallelipiped against the exponential growth of the number of vertices.

That’s interesting. I would be surprised if it’s not true in 4D and higher. I understand the growths you mentioned but I think Cavalieri’s principle still makes them all equal. I need to think more about it to be sure.

Actually, the $n$ vectors formed by the $n+1$ points  generate the same lattice irrespective of which edge directions you pick. And the parallelepiped is simply the fundamental parallelepiped of this lattice. All of them must have the same volume.

Take the unit cube in 4-space, and pick vertices 0000, 1000, 1110, 0101, 1011. The resulting determinant is $-2$ rather than $1$. So it's false in 4-space (unless I've done something stupid, or matlab computed the determinant wrong.).

I think we have different definitions of “parallelepiped generated by $n+1$ points”. What I mean is what I described in my last comment above in terms of lattice.

I was answering the OP's question: you're given 4 vertices of a parallelipiped, and are asked to compute the volume. I've given 5 points, $P_0 ... P_4$, that are vertices of two different parallelipeds: (a) The unit cube, and (b) the ppided whose edges from $P_0$ are $v_i = P_i - P_0,  (i = 1...4)$. These have different volumes, so the analog of OP's question is ambiguous in 4D.

Got it. We are in agreement.

TBH, when I tried concocting my example, I was thinking I'd fail because I was thinking of your argument! :)

BTW, see post-comment additions.
